# If sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $L$, then $x_{n+1}$ also tends do $L$

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = L$ exists where $(x_n)$ is a sequence. Why does $\lim x_{n+1} = L$?

My thought:

we know there exists an $N$ large so that $x_n $ will be very close to $L$ for all $n > N$. Since $n+1 > N$, then $x_{n+1}$ will be also very close to $L$. In fact, $x_{n+k} \to L$ for all $k>n$.

Is this reasoning good enough?

Comment: An argument containing a word like "very" is a very strong hint that some more precision is called for.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct but depending on your teacher/instructor it may or may not need some additional formalism.

Answer (score 2):

You can do better, with essentially the same reasoning you use: If $ x_n \to L$ is a convergent sequence and $ x_{n_k} $ is any subsequence, then $ x_{n_k} \to L$. As a proof, note that for any $ \epsilon > 0 $, we may find $ N $ such that for all $ n > N $, $ d(x_n, L) < \epsilon $. On the other hand, since $ n_k \geq k $, for $ k > N $ we have $ n_k > N $, and therefore $ d(x_{n_k}, L) < \epsilon $.

Comment: so you are saying that $(x_{n+1})$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)$?? I thought $x_{n+1}$ is the n+1th term of the sequence

Comment: Yes - why shouldn't that be a subsequence?

Comment: I get it now. because $(x_{n+1})$ is just the subsequence of the $(x_n)$ that has all the terms except $x_1$. Corect?